# Dúvida no estudo da abordagem de desenvolvimento Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, visual-studio-2010

Galera estou estudando as abordagens de desenvolvimento utilizadas no **Entity Framework** **6** as abordagens **Model First** e **Database First** encontrei facilmente na internet bons conteúdos e consegui compreender , mas a abordagem **Code First** está realmente complicada de achar o conteudo especifico da versão 6, posso estudar o code first usando os exemplos das versões 4.1 ? muda realmente tanta coisa assim ?

Comment: Sim, pode usar, há algumas diferenças, mas nada usual, por sinal, eu sempre achei o contrário, material de code first é muito maior

Comment: Sim , mas e por que encontrei muita coisa com o pessoal usando a versão 4.1 ai fiquei meio que na dúvida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Posso estudar o code first usando os exemplos das versões 4.1?

Pode mas evite usar a abordagem por EDMX, que já está ultrapassada. [O melhor tutorial que conheço é este](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) e logo devo estar escrevendo um curso em português com vários acréscimos. Se interessar, só se manifestar por comentário.

> Muda realmente tanta coisa assim?

A questão é que várias coisas foram abandonadas, como o que eu falei sobre o EDMX acima. O problema do EDMX é que ele exige que o arquivo central de modelos esteja sempre atualizado, e não permite uma alfaiataria muito extensa quanto aos campos e validações dos seus *Models*.

Hoje a abordagem se concentra em deixar o programador o mais livre possível para as possibilidades de projeto, e o EDMX engessa muito isso.

Comment: Tenho interesse no curso para Code First. Estou com o mesmo problema do colega, muito conteudo nos outros modelos e CodeFirst quase nada.
Estou aprendendo muita coisa na tora, ta indo mas poderia ser mais agil.
Tenho outras duvidas como dataanotation VS FluentAPI, to batendo cabeça porem a curva de aprendizagem esta bem melhor que no Java.
O legal do EDMX eu acho é a capacidade de visualização de maneira macro os relacionamentos, pena que tudo que leio informa que o mesmo esta ficando fora de uso, tem alguma outra ferramenta que traga a visualização dos relacionamentos da forma que o EDMX faz?

Comment: Tem, mas de uma forma mais agnóstica. Eu só recomendo o uso do EDMX pra uma modelagem inicial. Depois simplesmente não vale a pena continuar usando, porque o EDMX gera todos os *Models* novamente e acaba com a alfaiataria. Eu vou estar escrevendo este curso neste fim de ano e avisarei a todos os interessados.

Comment: Eu to usando somente para a parte inicial mesmo, porem toda parte de validação e ajustes ele arrebenta na primeira alteração.

Comment: Exatamente. Isto me motivou a escrever o curso. Logo vou começar a divulgar aqui e te aviso.

Comment: Opa, também tenho interesse!

Comment: Eu tenho interesse por favor comente aqui quando estiver disponível =D